# Selecting from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, orders and old_orders.

Each table has some similar fields and some different fields.

I want to select name and id from both tables and output all of the orders from both tables.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to give more information. Are the tables related in any way? Please post their structure.

Comment: This is nothing to do with joins. If anything it's a union.

Comment: I dont want a join, I want to just select data from both tables.

Comment: Why vote this down? The question is fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quess what you want is [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html), ie

```
SELECT name, id FROM orders WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT name, id FROM orders_old WHERE ...
```